# Is scringo still working?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, chat, scringo

anyone knows if scringo is officially down? I have read some comments about it.
I am trying to use Scringo in my project and after merging manifests and adding the library, I get the error:

```
10-11 22:29:58.125: E/Scringo(12075): Error fetching
10-11 22:29:58.125: E/Scringo(12075): java.io.FileNotFoundException:https://srv1.scringo.com/ScringoServer2/api?command=getAppData&clientType=2&build=2.5.4&appId=aFZeiXQFSH3pgscgbq878CU3xJfXCDTh&changeNumber=0&v=15
10-11 22:29:58.125: E/Scringo(12075):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
10-11 22:29:58.125: E/Scringo(12075):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
10-11 22:29:58.125: E/Scringo(12075):   at com.scringo.utils.ScringoHttpFetcher.getResponseStr(ScringoHttpFetcher.java:132)
10-11 22:29:58.125: E/Scringo(12075):   at com.scringo.utils.ScringoJsonFetcher.handleResponse(ScringoJsonFetcher.java:59)
10-11 22:29:58.125: E/Scringo(12075):   at com.scringo.utils.ScringoJsonFetcher.run(ScringoJsonFetcher.java:40)
```

in my project and in the sampleapp available in github, so, is it working? if it is, any suggestion to my problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource with the specified uri does not exist.

**GET *Request*** **:** https://srv1.scringo.com/ScringoServer2/api?build=2.5.4&appId=aFZeiXQFSH3pgscgbq878CU3xJfXCDTh&v=15&clientType=2&command=getAppData&changeNumber=0

**503 Service Unavailable:** Back-end server is at capacity       0 bytes       48 ms

Comment: The thing is I created my app this morning and started the instructions today and suddenly the website stopped working. I know the server is down but I actually want to know if anyone knows if Scringo stopped operating or it's just they lost their server today and will be up in a few hours. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Probably some unrelated downtime... Scringo is live and the link is working now